# Custom Widget options in theme

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I want to reprogram my first sketch of our theatre club page in wordpress but until now I only have basic knowledge of creating wp pages. As I want the theme to be as customizable as possible I want to add options to the widget according their appearance.

My Sketch (That was developed using a node.js framework) is live under this domain: http://tud-schauspielstudio.de/

I want my theme to show a big widget area on the start page and each widget needs to get information about how it should be displayed, that generate different classes of the corresponding widget.

is it posible to add options to widgets (that are not written by me) from my theme?

Comment: What do you mean "options that are not written by me"? If you want to add options, you must write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Look at the [in_widget_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/in_widget_form/) hook. Saving to the instance is the [widger_update_callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_update_callback/) hook.